# Is there a way to count rows in R without loading data first?

Tags: r

I have a few large CSVs for which I need to know the number of records contained in each. I know I can do this by loading the data into R and using nrow(), but it will take quite a while for all the data to load into R first given the size of the files. Is there any shortcut route that would allow me to count the records without first loading the data?

Thanks

Comment: Try `length(count.fields(...))`

Comment: What OS are you using? Utilities like `wc` on unix-like systems can count the number of lines in a file, bit there's no way to know with a csv file without reading the entire file. It's even harder if you have embedded newlines in values in your data.